# Hot to add a View to a Scrollview programmatically using layout constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm triying to instert programatically a view inside an UIScrollView, but it doesn't appear here is my code:

```
mainScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


        self.view.addSubview(mainScrollView)

        //Add Trailing
        let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mainScrollView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        self.view.addConstraint(trailingConstraint)

        //Add Leading
        let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mainScrollView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        self.view.addConstraint(leadingConstraint)

        //Add Top
        let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mainScrollView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        self.view.addConstraint(topConstraint)

        //Add Bottom
        let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mainScrollView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        self.view.addConstraint(bottomConstraint)

        let contentView = UIView()
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.backgroundColor = .blue
        mainScrollView.addSubview(contentView)

        //Add Trailing
        let trailingConstraintContent = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: mainScrollView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        mainScrollView.addConstraint(trailingConstraintContent)

        //Add Leading
        let leadingConstraintContent = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: mainScrollView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        mainScrollView.addConstraint(leadingConstraintContent)

        //Add Top
        let topConstraintContent = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: mainScrollView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        mainScrollView.addConstraint(topConstraintContent)

        //Add Bottom
        let bottomConstraintContent = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: mainScrollView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        mainScrollView.addConstraint(bottomConstraintContent)
```

The first ScrollView is inserted because I added a background color and I can see it, but I cant see the contentview added as background color blue.

Any help?

**UPDATE**

I have tried the following to and no success:

```
mainScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let contentView = UIView()
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        mainScrollView.backgroundColor = .red
        contentView.backgroundColor = .blue

        self.view.addSubview(mainScrollView)
        mainScrollView.addSubview(contentView)

        let viewsDictionary = ["mainScrollView": mainScrollView, "contentView": contentView]

        let mainScrollViewVerticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[mainScrollView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
        let mainScrollViewHorizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[mainScrollView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
        self.view.addConstraints(mainScrollViewVerticalConstraint)
        self.view.addConstraints(mainScrollViewHorizontalConstraint)

        let contentViewVerticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[contentView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
        let contentViewHorizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[contentView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
        mainScrollView.addConstraints(contentViewVerticalConstraint)
        mainScrollView.addConstraints(contentViewHorizontalConstraint)
```

Comment: I think you should add width and height for contentView

Comment: But if I'm telling that the contentview traits, leads and top and down, it should get all the space of the scrollView or not?

Comment: yes, but not enough. scrollView need to know content's width and height to scroll. let set scrollView's contentSize or set width and height for contentView

Comment: did my answer help ?

Answer (score 0):

When adding sub views the important thing to remember is to pin them in a way to make it possible for Auto Layout to evaluate the height, this is because the scroll view determines the content size by determining the sum of heights sub views (in case of vertical).
So you should specify the height in VFL . eg.

```
let contentViewVerticalConstraint=NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[contentView(300)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
```

Comment: I tried adding it buy i can't see the other color view inside :S

Answer (score -2):

- Create a custom view using .xib file
- Apply the constraints for the custom view child components in .xib (auto layout)
- Create a custom view instant

  MyView *myview = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"nibName" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
- Set its frame for screen width as

  CGRect screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
  myView = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, screenSize.width, 100.0);
- Add to parent view

  [parentView addSubView:myView];

Comment: I need with autolayout and programatically, the view is generated from a json.